“Oh No” screen, and can’t startx after Ubuntu 24.04 upgrade from 22.04
I encountered no errors during the process. Towards the end my background went black but i wrote that off… I looked at the other answers with the Oh No screen but my case seems different since I can’t get to a login screen via ctl alt f3, or the other keystroke variations.
I changed from gdm3 to lightdm and now I can get to the splash login screen. When I login it just goes back to the Oh No screen unfortunately. My touchpad can move the mouse but not click.
I plugged in an external mouse and now i can try different desktop options. Selecting Wayland got me a black screen, however OpenBox actually worked. So I no longer think its an nvidia driver issue. Maybe it has to do with my track pad??
Any hints at this point?

Update: out of desperation I decided to wget the latest official nvidia proprietary drivers, ran that installer. It seemed to be very concerned about removing nouveau and it did a lot of things including writing an xorg.conf file.
With that xorg.conf file however, boot up just gets stuck at a black screen. If I delete it I am just back to the login page with the Oh No following. Looking the xorg.log I am seeing the final lines NVIDIA(G0) Failed to set the display configuration. Setting mode on head 0 failed: insufficient permissions then Deleting GPU-0.

I seem to think that /etc/X11/xorg.conf has something to do with things. If I keep the one that the nvidia driver creates then startx doesn’t error out but it seems to just give me a black screen. If I delete it then I get the “Oh no” page routine. Looking into the xorg.logs i see that it’s complaining about a busID, so i am guessing it needs that from the conf file Device section. Experimenting with removing parts of the xorg.conf…not having much luck.

Maybe its safe to say at this point that it is a graphics driver issue since at least my mouse and keyboard etc worked in safe graphics mode?

First a recap of the issue:

accepted System upgrade from 22.04->24.04 via UI. There were no errors, but at the end before reboot my background went black.
After reboot went straight to "Oh No" Screen of death.

Logged in as root via recovery menu (press escape during boot up)
Assumed the issue was nvidia drivers, spent a long time trying all sorts of options, and blacklisting nouveau via configs and kernel parameters. It was not nvidia driver issue, nvidia-smi worked but it was confusing since the Xorg logs would frequently say things about loading Nouveau, even though it was blacklisted etc. Some sort of driver conflict like that seemed a reasonable explanation but this was a goose chase: 560 drivers are working for the RTX 3060, and I tried to create new users to login with but that was no help.
Solution:

log in as root with network enabled (or if you can get to a log in with ctl atl f3 just do that, i couldnt)
install lightdm
edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and uncomment WaylandEnable=true
install or reinstall gnome-desktop, genome-session, ubuntu-desktop
reboot
hopefully the login GUI shows up
using a mouse that works (i had to plug one in as my trackpad wouldnt click, and couldnt find a keyboard way) change the log-in session to Gnome-Wayland
If you see a black screen with a little rectangle on the upper left, dont worry, you are in Gnome but with a blank background!
right click and select a background photo
reboot
now selecting "ubuntu-desktop on wayland" should work.

Now everything basically looks the same as it did in 22.04 except there is a trashcan icon with an x through it on my desktop complaining about some permissions thing...shrugs
Not 100% sure that this was fixed by changing the background image in gnome, but i tried multiple times to login to ubuntu-wayland only to get sent into the Oh No screen before I made that change. I was actually planning on just settling with Gnome3, but decided to try one last time after I couldnt get the dash to show up on my desktop, and it worked...

If you get the "Oh No" screen during a major version upgrade, likely the upgrade was aborted, and you will need to play with apt to complete the upgrade process.
Very frequently, when the video driver does not load correctly on nvidia cards, the partially initialized GUI hangs and leaves the keyboard in an unusable state, so the ctrlaltFkey sequence doesn't work (actually, even caps lock wouldn't work).  There are several ways to get out of this, but the easiest is to add nomodeset in the kernel command line from grub.  (I have detailed that process at Why Ubuntu 24.04.1 only works on on one computer, but shows black screen after installation on several other computers? )
One possible cause for this is that your video driver did not build correctly (or was interrupted and didn't finish), and by changing video driver versions, you have forced it to rebuild successfully.
There are two possible routes to get past the next error.  You can look for a log file (likely in your home directory) to find out what is crashing when you attempt to log in and then fix that.  (If you find more errors this way that you can't correct, add them to the question.)
Alternately, with prior knowledge of how you got in this state, you can try to repair it.  With the assumption this was caused by an aborted upgrade, you can complete the upgrade with dpkg --configure -a followed by apt full-upgrade and fix errors and repeat until everything finishes without error and it says there are no updates to install.  (That might have fixed the video driver too.)
Since you say you are getting to the login prompt now, there are a few more possibilities.

Possibly your desktop GUI got (partially?) uninstalled, and something like apt install ubuntu-desktop may fix it.

Possibly even though your GUI is now working at the login prompt, it isn't actually working well enough to support gnome because you still have the wrong video driver.  It may be possible to install a non-gnome desktop or failsafe GUI to test this.  However if nvidia-smi sees your video card then this is probably not the issue.

You may have something corrupt in your user profile that is crashing when you log in.  The easiest way to test this is to log in as a different user and see if it's just your account.  (Maybe create a temporary account to test?)  If you confirm it is your account, or don't have another account to try, you can try renaming the configuration directories.  Something like:
mkdir oldconfig
mv .gnome* .local oldconfig/


Note that this is destructive and may damage other parts of your account profile, but is reversible.
Destroying your user profile config is kind of a last resort.  It would be better to dig through config files and find the actual error unless you have prior knowledge that your profile might have gotten corrupted.

Thanks for the comment! I tried apt full-upgrade but I get 0 upgraded 0 newly installed 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded, so i think the install actually completed? It also appears that Ubuntu-desktop is installed and upgraded as well.
At this point i am getting to the login page, but when i try to login it throws the “oh no” screen. I can now alt ctl f3 to get to a cmd line at least. But I feel like I have tried everything and nothing is moving the needle. Dmesg is just showing some Bluetooth errors from what i can tell, and they seem to change every time…

Added some more steps and clarified the upgrade finished part.

I did try creating a brand new user and logging in as that but got the same result.
One thing I would add is that my track pad button doesn’t seem to work on the login page, although i can move the mouse around and the keyboard seems to work. Could there be some kind of firmware issue with other non-gpu hardware? I am deterministically seeing these in dmesg ACPI BIOS Error(bug): Failure creating named object, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS etc..

It sounds like there are still driver issues.  Looking through the logs (Xorg.log? wayland log?) may shed light on that.  Looking for logs in your profile directories may also help.

Do you know if there is a safe way to downgrade to 22.04?

Reinstall is the only way.  But likely you'll end up with the same issue.

I managed to get OpenBox working. Would prefer to have more of a desktop, but i think it beats a destructive reinstall for now, and I guess it shows that its not the nvidia drivers?
